# Creating a list of lists as a function of a list

Tags: programming

I have a list of length n whose elements are all 1 and -1. For each -1 in the list i want to create a list with a -1 in the same spot and a 1 everywhere else.

For example:
A list like {-1, -1, 1} would give me {{-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}}.

Also, if the input list is {1, 1, 1}, I want to get {{-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}}.

I know how to do this in other languages such as python but have no idea how to do 
this in mathematica.

Comment: I can't follow your examples.  I see that in Nasser's answer he uses the `Position` of `-1` for the first and then `1` for the second.  Is this what you intended?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I understood it as 2 different problems/questions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard , Yeah thats what I intended. To further elaborate on the example, I basically want to split a list, call it A, into multiple lists such that when you multiply those lists together component wise, you get back the original list A. The list containing all 1's is a special case though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a = {-1, -1, 1}
ones = Table[1, {Length[a]}];
ReplacePart[ones, # -> -1] & /@ Position[a, -1]

(* {{-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}} *)

a = {1, 1, 1};
ones = Table[1, {Length[a]}];
ReplacePart[ones, # -> -1] & /@ Position[a, 1]

(* {{-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}} *)
```

Update to combine into one function:

```
foo[a_List] := Module[{ones = Table[1, {Length[a]}], p = -1},
  If[FreeQ[a, -1], p = 1]; (*assumed all 1 in this case*)
  ReplacePart[ones, # -> -1] & /@ Position[a, p]
  ];

 foo[{-1, -1, 1}]
 (* {{-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}}  *)
 foo[{-1, -1, 1, -1}]
 (* {{-1, 1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 1, -1}} *)


 foo[{1, 1, 1}]
 (* {{-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}} *)
```

If you prefer a stronger test for all ones in a list (in the above I assumed if it has no -1, then it must be all ones case), then use the following:

```
foo[a_List] := Module[{ones = Table[1, {Length[a]}], p = -1},
  If[And @@ (# == 1 & /@ a), p = 1]; (*checks that all elements are 1*)
  ReplacePart[ones, # -> -1] & /@ Position[a, p]
  ]
```

Comment: Cool, thanks. Is there a way to turn this into a single function that just takes in the original list as an argument. I feel like Would have to use if statements in a procedural way but I have no idea how to do that in mathematica.

Comment: @ra91 yes. Will update to one function.

Answer (score 4):

Just another way (if I have interpreted correctly):

```
fun[m_] := With[{p = Position[m, -1], w = 1 - 2 IdentityMatrix[Length@m]}, 
  If[p == {}, w, Extract[w, p]]]
```

So,

```
Column[# -> fun@# & /@ Tuples[{-1, 1}, 3]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Following your clarification and inspired by ubpdqn's answer I propose:

```
f[a:_List] := Pick[1 + 2 DiagonalMatrix[a], a, -1]
f[a:{1..}] := f[-a]
```

Test:

```
f @ {-1, -1, 1}
f @ {1, 1, 1}
```

> ```
> {{-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}}
>
> {{-1, 1, 1}, {1, -1, 1}, {1, 1, -1}}
> ```

Comment: it is very nice to think I could 'inspire' you...and I really like the terseness of the answer:)

Comment: @ubpdqn In that case I'll try to always mention it as this surely isn't the first time. :-)  You often have a rather nice and sometimes unconventional approach to a problem.  I hope I have mentioned this before.  By the way your code used to be a little rough and I would sometimes edit it but I only bothered to do so because I liked your ideas.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard...amateur's luck...but sincerely appreciate the words of encouragement...the variety that springs forth from Mathematica and this user group is a wonderful environment to learn in :)